# Apple event not getting added to calender

Tags: swift, ekevent

I am trying to add event to apple calendar 
Below is my code

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy h:mm a"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateE)

        let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: appleEventStore)
        event.title = title!
        event.startDate = date!
        event.endDate = date!
        event.notes = text

        let alarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -3600)
        event.addAlarm(alarm)

        let location = EKStructuredLocation(title: address!)
        location.radius = 1000.0
        location.geoLocation = CLLocation(latitude:(location?.latitude)!, longitude:(.location.longitude)!)
        event.structuredLocation = location

        event.calendar = appleEventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

        do {
            try appleEventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        }
 catch let e as NSError {
        let message = "Failed to add event to Calender ::" + e.description
         }
```

I am getting error shown in screenshot,Event is not getting added to calendar

[image]

please any one knows this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you set EKStructuredLocation for event and default calendar (defaultCalendarForNewEvents) is Exchange type I was getting this exception.

Checking type of calendar and setting EKEvent parameters solved my issue

for details https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4788423?tstart=0